# Magento2: How to execute Cron in non-root container on Kuberentes?

Tags: magento2, cron, docker, containers

I've used the Bitnami Magento Helm chart to install Magento 2 on the Kubernetes cluster.

By default, the pod and the container are configured not to use root users which is good from a security point of view.
But because of running as a non-root user, Magento can't execute Cron jobs.

Are there any ways to execute Cron using a non-root user? Why can't a non-root user execute Cron?